# How to debug remote v8-based application using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, remote-debugging, v8

v8 has its own JSON based remote-debugging protocol and two UI debuggers:console application D8 and a eclipse plugin(hosted at http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools)

Chrome use WebKit Remote Debugging Protocol including Console, DOM Debugger, ..., **Debugger**

> "WebKit Remote Debugging Protocol" is a Google Chrome/Chromium debug protocol. You will find its description at http://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

So is it possible to use the Chrome Dev Tools ships with chrome to debug remote v8-based application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Node Webkit Agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) for NodeJS version >= 0.6
Node-inspector is for NodeJS version 0.4

The setup need to be set in your node server and access the URL provided by the library base on your node version. You cannot use Developer Tools in Chrome directly.

Comment: node-inspector is very useful, chrome, safari and other webkit based web browser all works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) is designed to do exactly what you ask.

It seems that it competes with [Node Webkit Agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent).  I haven't tried webkit agent yet as it seems newer and it failed to install without some meddling.  node-inspector worked for me, and fairly well, although there is a bit of latency from running a statement to getting the output marshaled into Chrome's debugger.  Overall, it's an extremely useful tool.