# Remote Debugging Javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, remote-debugging

Is it possible to remote debug javascript files, served via a web server, i.e. thin, unicorn, etc? If yes, how? I've tried eclipse + chrome dev tools, but that seems to only work when files are opened via the file system.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use firebug to debug the javascript

Comment: I do use browser extensions for both firefox and chrome to debug in the browser, but I'm looking for a way to do that from an IDE (preferably eclipse based).

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/debug/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug remote v8-based application using Chrome Dev Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123285/how-to-debug-remote-v8-based-application-using-chrome-dev-tools)